# Are the following assumptions about indexing and ranking correct?

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, web-crawlers, google-index, google-ranking

Are the following statements true or false:

1. If a page is crawled by Google, it automatically gets into the index (unless explicitly blocked by `robots.txt`)
2. An indexed page always gets a ranking (high or low)
3. A page which is not referenced by any other pages, and which does not appear in a sitemap, will never be    crawled by Google, and will never get into the index
4. Google will update its index and ranking for some sites faster than for others
5. More popular sites are indexed and ranked faster than less popular sites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `1.` If a page is crawled by Google, it automatically gets into the index
>   (unless explicitly blocked by robots.txt).

False. The page can be crawled without being indexed. The page gets into the index except if it's not blocked by robots.txt or by meta robots noindex. On specific case I can't detail, a page only bocked by robots.txt can be indexed.

> `2.` An indexed page always gets a ranking (high or low).

True except if website is penalized. In that case, the page can be deleted from the index by Google.

> `3.` A page which is not referenced by any other pages, and which does not appear in a
>   sitemap, will never be crawled by Google, and will never get into the index.

True except if an internal or external link will point to this page in the future. Robots follow links...

> `4.` Google will update its index and ranking for some sites faster than for others.

I'm not sure but I think true by logic.

> `5.` More popular sites are indexed and ranked faster than less popular sites.

True. Trust websites are faster indexed and ranked than less trust websites. Indexation speed of a website also depends on number of links pointing to it.

Comment: `1.` "_The page gets into the index except if it's not blocked by robots.txt or by meta robots noindex._" - Not sure what you mean by this, is the double negative intentional? The page can be crawled without being indexed for any number of reasons, regardless of whether it is blocked or not. In fact, a page that is blocked only by robots.txt can still be indexed (URL only). If `5.` is true then `4.` must also be true.

Comment: 3 is false. Google can and _does_ make guesses at URL structure--at the very least with URL parameters. And Google has also been known to investigate non-linked text URLs.

Comment: @w3d: I agree with you. In details, a page that is blocked only by robots.txt can be indexed but it's specific case. I edited my answer. As you wish, you can complete my answer.

Comment: @Lèse majesté: I also agree with you, Google can know non-linked text URLs but I think the link is not indexed, it just appears in Webmaster tools.

Comment: #3 is also false for root domains. Google has access to all domains that are registered so can crawl any domain even with no links.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: Interesting, do you have any link which explains in details this point?

Comment: @Zistoloen I asked this question a while back: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22285/how-does-google-find-a-domain-with-no-links-to-it . I've also seen it mentioned elsewhere, don't remember exactly where though.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: Ok, thanks. I up voted your good question.