# How Googlebot discovers new website?

Tags: seo, googlebot

I have purchased a domain and uploaded with HTML Page and When I search in Google it shows my website.  Now my question is

1. How Google will discover my new website? I have not used
       sitemap,*robot.txt* and not included any kind Google plugin or
       tools.

**[This](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22285/how-does-google-find-a-domain-with-no-links-to-it)** Question is already posted but there is no perfect answer for that question so I asked once again.