# Is my Google search console property broken after creating it when the site was under construction?

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, technical-seo

Domain property and `https://www.example.com/` property are not getting indexed well

The thing is, I created the property before the under construction was deactivated on my WordPress website. Now some posts/pages are getting indexed but with the under construction in the sentence. Also the favicon does not display well.

At first I created a property `https://example.com/` and the URLs with www. didn't get indexed, this makes sense. So I deleted the property and created the `https://www`. property. Added the updated sitemaps again, and still no results. All I see is all my pages are not getting indexed.

at this point I have a domain property and the `https://www`. property. in my search console account. I have site kit installed, and my website is verified via DNS record, HTML file and meta tag in the header file which loads on all pages.
Also when I create a property Google says that domain is already verified, I deleted all verification methods before and it still is saying verified. Is this something Google has cached somehow? Is my domainname broken and should I start a new domainname or will Google get the results again? At this point I am clueless. Did I mess it up now?

Comment: Related: [Should I create a 'Website coming soon' page for my recently-acquired domain?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/89549/should-i-create-a-website-coming-soon-page-for-my-recently-acquired-domain/89575#89575)

Comment: Related: [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Google Search Console account is fine. You just need to give Google time to find and index your site. It takes Google a couple weeks before any changes you make to your site get reflected in Google Search Console. When you launch a new site, it often takes a year before Google indexes more than a couple pages from it.

Google Search Console and your sitemap have very little influence in getting your site indexed. Instead they provide stats to you about how your site is getting indexed. Google would find and index your site just fine even if you never created a search console account. Search console does little or nothing to speed up that process.

You should put your verification methods back. Google caches the verification for a while, but eventually your sites will lose verification and you won't be able to access their search console.

I would expect that Google will crawl and re-index your under-construction pages within 4 weeks. Over the coming months, more and more of your site will get indexed, but probably no more than a page or two per week.